# Basic polymorphism/inheritance issues

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism, super

I'm working with Java. I have done all of the research I could, but I could not find the answer to my question.There are certain parts of this code that I am not allowed to change and still fulfill the requirements of the assignment. I am working with seven classes. Class "Shape" looks like this:

```
package homework6;

public abstract class Shape{

protected String name;

public String getname(){
    return name;
}

abstract double getSurfaceArea();
}
```

I am not allowed to change any part of this class. The other classes are called Circle, Cylinder, Square, Geometric Shape, and the main class. Within each constructor I have been instructed to "set the name equal to the name of the object". I have done that the same way for each class, EG:

```
package homework6;

public class Rectangle extends Shape{

public double length;
public double width;

public Rectangle(){
    length = 0;
    width = 0;
    name = "Rectangle";
}

public Rectangle(double l, double w){
    length = l;
    width = w;
    name = "Rectangle";   
}

double getSurfaceArea(){
    return length*width;
}

}
```

Here is the problem. In my main class, which I am also not able to change, there is some test code. Everything in my program works correctly except the "name" portion. In the code below, "getName" is underlined red and the error is "cannot find symbol". I have tried experimenting with the 'super' keyword and I was not able to make it work. I have been working on this for days, I have watched countless youtube videos, but I cannot figure this out.

public static void main(String args[]) {

```
    Shape list_of_shapes[] = new Shape[10];

    list_of_shapes[0] = new Circle();         
    list_of_shapes[1] = new Circle(1.5);                                    

    list_of_shapes[2] = new Rectangle();        
    list_of_shapes[3] = new Rectangle(3.5, 2);                            

    list_of_shapes[4] = new Square(); 
    list_of_shapes[5] = new Square(4.5);   

    list_of_shapes[6] = new Cylinder();         
    list_of_shapes[7] = new Cylinder(1.5, 2);   


    boolean skipLine = false;
    for(Shape s : list_of_shapes)
    {

        if(s instanceof Circle && !(s instanceof Cylinder))
        {
            System.out.println("Object of class " + s.getName() + " with radius = " + ((Circle)(s)).radius + ",");
            System.out.println("has an area of " + s.getSurfaceArea());
        }
        else if (s instanceof Rectangle && !(s instanceof Square))
        {
            System.out.println("Object of class " + s.getName() + " with length = " + ((Rectangle)(s)).length + " and width = " + ((Rectangle)(s)).width + ",");
            System.out.println("has an area of " + s.getSurfaceArea());
        }
        else if (s instanceof Square)
        {
            System.out.println("Object of class " + s.getName() + " with length = " + ((Square)(s)).length + " and width = " + ((Square)(s)).width + ",");
            System.out.println("has an area of " + s.getSurfaceArea());
        }
        else if (s instanceof Cylinder)
        {
           System.out.println("Object of class " + s.getName() + " with radius = " + ((Cylinder)(s)).radius + " and height = " + ((Cylinder)(s)).height + ",");
            System.out.print("has an area of " + s.getSurfaceArea());
            System.out.println(" and a volume of " + ((Cylinder)(s)).getVolume());
        }
```

The surface area shows up correctly but I am not sure what I need to do in order to get the names to show up. I cannot add any methods or constructors that do not already exist: the name is supposed to be pulled from the constructors that already exist, somehow.

Comment: In addition to Anubian Noob answer I'd add that using `instanceof` operator defeats the purpose of inheritance and polymorphism. What you want to do is to let every specialization of `Shape` to have its custom behavior (let it be area calculation or printing the details) to avoid checking the runtime type dynamically.

Comment: Holy crap. Anubian Noob.... I can't believe I made such an amateurish mistake. Finals have truly fried my brain. THANK YOU, THAT WORKED.

Comment: Here's the thing -- my teacher is the one who wrote the main method and told us to just leave it as it is, just use it to make sure our code works. We were never even taught what "instanceof" means, or what it is for.

Comment: I hope this teacher of yours doesn't teach programming for a living.

Comment: It's to determine if an instance is an `instanceof` the `class`.

Comment: @DavidWallace, it's nice, *and easy*, to judge from afar. It's painfully obvious that the code is academic. perhaps some context is needed before throwing stones wildly.

Comment: So we get a generation of programming graduates who think that a whole lot of `if/else` branches with `instanceof` operators is the right way to implement polymorphism?  At various times in my career, I have had to work with such people - I have the right to throw stones as wildly as I like.  @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: Yes, he does.... he has never even held a job prior to teaching at my college. Three people including myself have raised complaints. Luckily this is my last assignment for this class (but I'm sure I will be back here soon enough.... fortunately he did not kill my interest in programming).

Comment: Well, in fairness, I doubt this person has the reach to corrupt an entire generation of graduates. I'm simply saying you weren't there for the entire course and now you cast judgement on someone without knowing anything about it. Perhaps the professor is setting them up to say..."but that was insanity; isn't there a better way?" The best professor I've had taught like that and I, according to me ;), am turning out fine. There's plenty of good and bad code examples. I could easily cherry pick one that makes him look foolish - but why? @DavidWallace.

Comment: Look, I've worked as a teacher, and had to fix up "damage" done by my predecessor.  I've worked with junior programmers who think that the best way of solving a particular problem is whatever abomination their college professor did, and need to be "uneducated" in a hurry.  One thing that I do know is that a professor has very little control over which bits out of what they teach will be forgotten, and which immortalised.  Writing code like this and giving it to students is really kind of dangerous, whether the professor knows better or not.  @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: Me too, in an unrelated field but teaching is teaching. The truth is there's different teaching and learning skills/preferences. You won't get a perfect match every time with every student. I spend ~3x the amount of time in class teaching myself. Nothing *any* professor has said to me was accepted as gospel; so I trust but verify. What's dangerous is to believe shielding students from bad code is the best way. How will they identify it when they see it? OP didn't even know what `instanceof` did despite it's obviousness so...Agree to disagree shall we? @DavidWallace.

Comment: @Chief Two Pencils I understand this is an argument of philosophy, and I appreciate your help, but could we not insult me? This professor cannot properly speak or write, in spite of the fact that English is his first language, he cannot spell, he "teaches" using powerpoint presentations, he releases his two hour class an hour early, goes out of town when assignments are due and refuses to check his email, answers questions in class with "I don't know," and has emailed us after every class period to tell us that most of what he just taught was incorrect. Yeah, I'm a noob, but it isn't my fault.

Comment: My apologies; I didn't mean any of that to be insulting. I was trying to say that it's clear the person *isn't* teaching you this is the best way. If that was true wouldn't they need to explain the code they're using (i.e.; the instanceof operator). And it's possible this person is a tool and shouldn't be teaching you. Mr. Wallace didn't know that and IMHO asserting to a student that their teacher is bad, or worse, after seeing a single out-of-context section of code is [insert an appropriate non-offensive word of "your" choice here]. ;)

Comment: In this particular case, the teacher provided "model code" for the students to include in their assignment.  I believe that when doing so, any teacher should make sure that their code is absolutely perfect, as far as the capacity of the students to understand will allow.  If I had written a horrible kludge like this one, I'd be ashamed of it - I wouldn't be showing it to students so they could copy it, and learn from my poor example.  I feel that there's a huge difference between giving students poor code as a model to learn from; and giving poor code, with a disclaimer such as "here's one ...

Comment: ... way of doing XYZ, it's not the best way, and I'll show you a better way in next week's lesson".  Maybe what I said was insulting to Derpentine's teacher, but frankly, I'm sick and tired of having to re-educate graduates who produce revolting code, because that's what their professors have taught them to do.  @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: So I guess no agreeing to disagree...OP says "There are certain parts of this code that I am not allowed to change" and "which I am also not able to change". And that's the point. Your argument seems to be more about your reputation and not so much about the outcome for a student. I can absolutely take the code above and teach someone as good if not better than anyone who's concerned about being "ashamed". You also seem to be talking in circles. Previously you said the professor had no control over what is remembered..., yet you seem pretty confident they're absolutely capable of learning...

Comment: ...everything bad. You also quote and then assume that this "model" code was meant to learn from yet they tell them in so many words to completely disregard it. That doesn't sound like an instruction to learn. I guess what I'm sick of is people making baseless accusations and speculative comments about something second hand. Perhaps I've got a tad too much desire to treat people with a general respect and not assume I'm the final decider of all things which I know nothing about. @DavidWallace. I call it the golden rule and an efficient way to avoid looking like an ass. Good day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the method:

```
public String getname(){
```

You're calling it like this:

```
s.getName()
```

Java, like many languages, is case sensative.

I think it's just a typo with the library (it *should* be `getName`, but if it is `getname` just use that).

---

Also, in your `Rectangle` constructor:

```
public Rectangle(){
    length = 0;
    width = 0;
    name = "Rectangle";
}
```

You can just use `this` to call the other constructor. It just makes your code simpler and removes duplicate functionality.

```
public Rectangle() {
    this(0, 0)
}
```